# Find the location/Position of JFrame in the window

Tags: java, swing, location, jframe

I am trying to find the Starting location/position of the JFrame in order to map the mouse cursor from the  JFrame window to desktop. Is there anyway to find the X,Y position of JFrame ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`getLocation()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation%28%29) or [`getLocationOnScreen()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) method of [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) which are inherited from java.awt.Component.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the MouseListener Interface and call the override methods

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
```

and use

```
MouseEvent.getX();

MouseEvent.getXOnScreen();
```