# Detecting windows in the background

Tags: java, windows

I just made my first Java application, but it's not very useful. All it does is create a JFrame which covers the screen and has an opacity of 0.01 and no borders, and it's also always in the front. This makes it so the user cannot interact with the background. I'm thinking of turning it into a game in which the windows open in the background act as battlegrounds. How do I detect windows, their positions, and their sizes?

Comment: `I'm thinking of turning it into a game in which the windows open in the background act as battlegrounds` - the background should NOT be separate windows. A game should be in a self contained window. You use images or panels for the backgrounds of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the goal of these windows but this existing topic should help you: 
[Find the location/Position of JFrame in the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950726/find-the-location-position-of-jframe-in-the-window)

(and read about the official documentation, don't forget inherited methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)